# Retornar array desde archivo JSON JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, http

Estoy haciendo una programa que saca datos de un archivo .json local, cree una función llamada cargarProds() que extrae los objetos y realice un console.log de esos datos. El problema es que cuando retorno el array con los objetos y hago el console.log me aparece undefined. A continuación les dejo el código:

```
var prods = cargarProds();
console.log(prods);

function cargarProds(){
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET', '../../data.json', true);
    xhttp.send();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            prods = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(prods);
            return prods;
        };
    }
};
```

Se agradece la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví, era tan sencillo como agregar esta línea de código al principio:

```
const jsonData= require('../../data.json'); 


var prods = jsonData;
```

De esta manera tengo los productos cargados en mi js

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.